# Racket : Run scheme file in terminal and show result

Tags: scheme, racket

I need to run a basic Scheme script and get his output.
Let's take this example :

test.scm

```lisp
(define square ( lambda (x) (* x x)))
(square 3)
```

And when I run `racket -f test.scm`, I didn't get the result of `(square 3)`.

How can I run the file and get return values displayed as is the case when I wrote it in the interactive mode.

(I can run racket with -i but I don't want to call my functions each time I run the script) Thanks !

Comment: Why would you expect `racket -f tp1.scm` to run a function in `test.scm`?

Comment: Oups, sorry, it's racket -f test.scm !

Comment: Did you try `racket test.scm`?

Comment: You have two options. 1) Switch to `#lang racket` (and invoke the file with `racket test.rkt`) and get the automatic printing or 2) keep the current setup, but you need to manually add `(println ....)` in places that you want the result to be printed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Racket and it's non Scheme language `#lang racket` prints the result of all top level expressions unless it is the same object as when evaluating `(void)`.

If you look at the [guide](https://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/racket.html#%28part._start-module-mode%29) you'll see that you can simply just supply the file path as an argument without swicthes:

```
racket test.scm # prints "9\n" and exits
```

And Bob's your uncle